# Where can I find sustainable investments?

Tags: money, local

I'm currently into lowering as much as possible my consumption of expendable goods. This has already had an effect on my daily expenses: I buy in short-cycle and second-hand, and as I have a relatively high income, I keep having spare money at the end of the month.

Question is: Do you know of websites, or institutions where I could go to finance projects pursuing sustainability actions? the key points:

- I obviously don't want to buy new useless stuff,
- I don't want to invest in senseless companies in stock market, or in basic bank products,
- I'm not really into funding around the globe, I prefer to boost my country/region to change for sustainability (France/IDF/Paris),
- It's better to fund/finance than to donate (so there will be more money available in the long term), so I'm looking for projects, return on investments etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In France there is an interesting investment solution in sustainable development called [La Nef](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Nef_(entreprise)), *Nouvelle Économie Fraternelle*. [Here is the official site](https://www.lanef.com/la-nef/)

They are here for quite a long time and offer investments in projects that are ***positive*** to people and nature:

- socially responsible (32%)
- environmental(63%)
- artistic(5%)

You are even invited to release part of the interest to the profit of various associative projects.

## Declared values are:

- Transparency: the list of [funded projects year by year](https://www.lanef.com/la-nef/publications/?target=liste%20des%20pr%C3%AAts) is publicly available
- Ecology: around 60% of the money goes to "ecological" projects!
- Cooperate: each investor is a member of the cooperation (not sure of the exact meaning in English)

I myself have placement here for years. The yield is not the greatest you can find, but at least you know where your money goes, and capital is secure. You can even invest your time in the projects reviews and in the governance. This part I know less.

Comment: That is exactly his kind of projets I was looking for, thank you @j-chomel !

Answer (score -2):

If you're in the UK - https://www.ethex.org.uk/ and https://www.abundanceinvestment.com/ are awesome in what they provide.  Green Bonds are growing in popularity and are often used by renewable energy companies that are fundraising - so would also look out for those in your country.

Comment: If you don't describe this more, we are forced to follow the link.

Comment: Hi Tom, and welcome to the site. It'd be great if you could [edit] this and add a couple of sentences to describe how Ethex and Abundance meet the criteria set out in the question.